# when using gogo gosh scripts, how do I get print outs from all commands

Tags: osgi, pax, gogo-shell

I'm trying to automate the provisioning and searching of a service to speed up testing of changes to an OSGi system. I use Maven Pax:Provision to set up the environment from the various repositories.

I have some commands to load data from xml files and then some commands to search the services. 
The search commands all return a string describing the results.

I've a provision.tsl file with the commands to load the osgi environment and a search.tsl file that runs the search commands.
In the search.tsl I have a list of search command, each for the various tables I've loaded.
E.G.

```
echo Doing some searching
searchcell someTable someValue searchColumnName
echo search someOtherTable
searchcell someOtherTable someOtherValue searchColumnName
echo search yetAnotherTable
searchcell yetAnotherTable yetSomeOtherValue searchColumnName
```

However, when I run the search command E.G.

```
osgi> gosh search.tsl
```

I only get the result from the last command in the file. Echo works as normal though and looks like.

```
Doing some searching
search someOtherTable
search yetAnotherTAble
return results from searchCell yetAnotherTAble
```

Is this the expected behaviour for gosh?

Answer (score 0):

The gosh console automatically prints the value of each interactive command.

This makes it appear that your *searchcell* command is printing a result, when in fact it is returning a String, which *gogo* prints.

This doesn't work in scripts, so you either need to recode your *searchcell* command to print to stdout, or explicitly print each result in your script:

`echo Doing some searching
echo (searchcell someTable someValue searchColumnName)
echo search someOtherTable
echo (searchcell someOtherTable someOtherValue searchColumnName)`